# invalid %project specification: projection string value must start with a \'%\'

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-stitch

Using the Mongo Stitch SDK for iOS, trying to execute a projection using $elemMatch gives a weird error that doesn't occur using the same query structure on mongo shell.

```
var projection: Document = [
                    MongoFieldNames.pendingRequestsSent: [
                        "$elemMatch" : [
                            Fields.firebaseUserId : User.shared.metadata.userId 
                        ] as Document
                    ] as Document
                ]
```

That is how I create the query. But it gives me this error:

```
invalid %project specification: projection string value must start with a \'%\'
```

Comment: The $elemMatch is a projection that is currently not supported but will be soon. The '%' error that you're getting was a bug that's been fixed.

Comment: @haley - is `$meta` supported? I'm getting the same error for that...

Comment: @T3db0t This one is a bug, but is getting fixed (sorry!) :)

Comment: Bug is now fixed!